# How to toggle boolean value on click with knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a view model that contains very basic "email" information:

```
var emailsViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.emails = ko.observableArray([
        {from: 'From', subject: 'Subject', date: '9/6/2015', flagged: false, read: false},
        {from: 'From', subject: 'Subject', date: '9/6/2015', flagged: false, read: false}
    ]);
}

ko.applyBindings(emailsViewModel);
```

These emails are displayed using a `for each` data bind:

```
<div id="email-browser" data-bind="foreach: emails">
    <div class="email" data-bind="css: {unread: read == false}">
        <div class="select"><input type="checkbox"></div>
        <div class="flag"><i class="fa fa-flag" data-bind="css: {flagged: flagged == true}></i></div>
        <div class="from" data-bind="text: from"></div>
        <div class="subject" data-bind="text: subject"></div>
        <div class="date" data-bind="text: date"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So basically, there are several "emails" that all have a from property, subject property, date property, flagged property, and read property.

I'm trying to figure out how I can toggle and update the boolean true/false value of the flagged and read properties on a click.  So, if a user were to click the `div` with a class of flag, it would toggle the object's boolean value from false to true or true to false.  Any idea on how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your `flagged` and `read` properties observables and then create functions in your view model to toggle these properties.

```
var emailsViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.emails = ko.observableArray([
        {from: 'From', subject: 'Subject', date: '9/6/2015', flagged: ko.observable(false), read: ko.observable(false)},
        {from: 'From', subject: 'Subject', date: '9/6/2015', flagged: ko.observable(false), read: ko.observable(false)}
    ]);

    self.toggleFlag = function(email){
    email.flagged(!email.flagged());
    };

    self.toggleRead = function(email){
    email.read(!email.read());
    }
}
```

Html

```
<div id="email-browser" data-bind="foreach: emails">
    <div class="email" data-bind="css: {unread: read() == false}">
        <div class="select"><input type="checkbox"></div>
        <div class="flag"><i class="fa fa-flag" data-bind="css: {flagged: flagged == true}"></i></div>
        <div class="from" data-bind="text: from"></div>
        <div class="subject" data-bind="text: subject"></div>
        <div class="date" data-bind="text: date"></div>
            <div class="toggle" data-bind="click: $root.toggleFlag, text: 'Flagged: '+ flagged()"></div>
            <div class="toggle" data-bind="click: $root.toggleRead, text: 'Read: '+read()"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Working example at: http://jsfiddle.net/newuserjs/oLh6u67z/1/

You can click on the `Flagged` and `Read` row and that will toggle the true/false value for each property.

Comment: Thank you so much. That did it. I just needed to put my actual properties into observables! I'm new to Knockout, so thanks for your help!

Comment: Just for clarification purposes and so I know exactly what your code is doing, can you do me a favor and explain what this line of code is actually doing? `email.flagged(!email.flagged());`

Comment: this line takes the current value of flagged observable, inverts it, and then assign it back to flagged observable. So, if its true, it becomes false and if the value is false, it become true.

Answer (score 2):

You should make email property 'flagged' observable and bind it in the markup with 'click' binding.

```
self.toggleFlag = function(item){
    item.flagged(!item.flagged());
};
```

See my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/brainboost/bjfs1a1u/

Answer (score 0):

using knockout mapping plugin, it is rather easy to populate observable arrays with objects containing observable properties.
I'd imagine your email list comes from a server call? If so, than it would probably be json format, or javascript objects ... using the mapping plugin, you convert those objects into fully observable.